# beamer/multimedia -- no sound (Ubuntu 18.04, TeXLive 2015)

Tags: beamer, multimedia, audio

I am not sure if my problem is no sound being added to the pdf file or my reader(s) not working. I have tried pdfpc and the default pdf reader and neither gives sound (even with an [example on the web](https://www2.le.ac.uk/departments/mathematics/extranet/staff-material/resource-downloads/beamer-presentation/BeamerExample.pdf) that is supposed to have sound. My source code follows. The produced pdf file is bigger than all sound files.

```
\documentclass[pdflatex]{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Start}

\begin{enumerate}
\item install audacity

\item record sound bytes as aiff, wav and mp3

\item process this file

\item pdfpc audiomulti.pdf

\item currently no sound from any frame
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Sound example --- mp3}

\sound[autostart,inlinesound]{}{io.mp3}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Sound example --- aiff}

\sound[autostart,inlinesound]{}{io.aiff}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Sound example --- wav}

\sound[autostart,inlinesound]{}{io.wav}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: platers => pdf readers (OOPS)

Comment: You can correct mistakes in your question by pressing the smaal `edit` link below your question. You can also format the code as code when you are editing the question, by selecting the code and pressing the code format button in the toolbar.

Comment: Much appreciated! Can I also attached my pdf file? It's 1.3 M.

Comment: You can't attach the pdf file, normally people post screenshots in their questions - although for your question that doesn't make sense of course. For the question itself: possible relevant information from the [beamer user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) (p143): "A bug in some versions of the Acrobat Reader makes it necessary to provide very exact details on the encoding of the sound file.  You have to provide the sampling rate, the number of channels (mono or stereo), the number of bits per sample, and the sample encoding method [...]

Comment: [...]  (raw, signed, Alaw orlaw). If you do not know this data or provide it incorrectly, the sound will be played incorrectly. It seems that you can only include uncompressed sound data, which can easily become huge. This is not required by the specification, but some versions of Acrobat Reader are unable to play any compressed data. Data formats that do work are `.aif` and `.au`"

Comment: As I mentioned I have been using Document Viewer (Evince) and pdfpc, neither of which give me sound from any of the formats I have tried.

Comment: Did you try with Acrobat reader ?